# How to assign a number from a list of lists to another list of lists in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list, like this one:

```
[[2, 4], [1, 2], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 10], [2, 3, 4]]
```

From the nested list, I want to take the max value from index 0 list and assign it to the index 1 list. Similarly, I take the max value from index 2 list and assign it to the index 3 list. Similarly it goes,like this should be the output:

```
{4: [1,2], 5:[3,4], 10: [2,3,4]}
```

Is there any possible way of doing this in Python 3?

Comment: Is your expected output supposed to be a dictionary?

Comment: Are you missing some terminology?

Comment: @James Yes, it's supposed to be a dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can zip together offset even strides of the list.

I think this is what you want:

```
a = [[2, 4], [1, 2], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 10], [2, 3, 4]]
{max(x): y for x,y in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])}
# returns:
{4: [1, 2], 5: [3, 4], 10: [2, 3, 4]}
```